# Windows Store App, ... cannot be used on the current platform. ERROR

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-store-apps, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I have Windows Store app which is actually a game and I'm trying to implement posting result on Facebook.
I'm using Facebook SDK for .Net from facebooksdk.net

Here's my code

```
        FacebookSession session = await App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync("publish_stream");
        if (session == null)
        {
            MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Error while getting publishing permissions. Please try again.");
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
            return;
        }

        // refresh your access token to contain the publish permissions
        App.AccessToken = session.AccessToken;

        FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(App.AccessToken);

        string message = "Your score is: " + points;
        dynamic proba = message;
        try
        {
            //The next line throws exception
            dynamic fbPostTaskResult = await fb.PostTaskAsync("/me/feed?message='{0}", proba);
            var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fbPostTaskResult;

            var successMessageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Posted Open Graph Action, id: " + (string)result["id"]);
            await successMessageDialog.ShowAsync();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageDialog exceptionMessageDialog = new MessageDialog("Exception during post: " + ex.Message);
            exceptionMessageDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
```

And the Exception Message that I recieve is:

> The API 'System.String.Get_FirstChar()' cannot be used on the current platform. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248273 for more information

I tried diffrent ways to send arguments to "PostTaskAsync()" method but I always got the same Exception. Searching Google and Stackoverflow wasn't much helpful.
I'm much grateful for any sort of help.
Cheers